# I need to grab the $_GET['loc'] that is sent via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have an `index.php` page where there are 2 kinds of queries first is location and secondly the search query. I am using ajax on location query

html structure :

```
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li><a href="?loc=dc">City</a></li>
  <li><a href="?loc=dn">North</a></li>
  <li><a href="?loc=ds">South</a></li>
</ul>
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
 </input value="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
<div id="content_from_AJAX">
 <ul id="li_start">
 </ul>
</div>
```

The `ajax.js` code :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    function getLoc(param){

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
         if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
         document.getElementById("li_start").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getresult.php"+param,false);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }

    //handle anchor clicks
    $("ul#location li a").click(function(){
        var loc = $(this).attr("href");
        getLoc(loc);
            return false;
    });

});
```

the `getresult.php` code :

```
require ('connect_to_mysql.php');
  if(isset($_GET['loc']) && empty($_GET['loc'])===false){
    $loc = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['loc']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM TB_name WHERE loc=";
  }
  else{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM TB_name";
  }

$query_run = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($query_run);

if($count<1){
 echo 'no result found';
}
else{
 while($result == mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
  echo "ALL results";
 }
// Here is what I want to be able o access on index.php
 return $_GET['loc']
}
```

I want the `$_GET` to be accessed on `index.php` so I can use it to filter result on search queries on the form above ie:

```
"SELECT * FROM `TB_name` WHERE `keyword` LIKE '$keyword' AND `loc`='".$_GET['loc']."'"
```

//I need to do this on `index.php` not on `getresult.php`

And also I want the `AJAX.js` to send queries on getresult.php if a user clicks on the loc links if the `$_POST['search']` isset.

Please help really need this project and I am starting to be so depressed X_X.. Thank you any help is appreciated alot :)

Comment: smells like sql injection :D

Comment: Hey hey stop man. Are you still traditional AJAX ? Switch to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: thnx for the tips just newbie here and trying to familiarize my self with ajax and understanding the concepts

Comment: I have a feeling that your $("ul#location li a").click function is not being called, as you do not have an UL element with that id. Is getLoc() being called at all? Test it out, strip out the Ajax and put an alert("hello world"); inside getLoc() then refresh the page and click away.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getresult.php"+param,false);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getresult.php?loc="+param,false);
                                 ^^^^ // forgot ?loc=
```

then use `$_GET["loc"]` in your getresult.php page.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs some rethinking. You have a dropdown with href links in it and a form that submits information (which it shouldn't if you want ajax results).

And why is your getresults.php doing a database query and then returning the GET variable back. That makes no sense, because the database query is now pointless as its results are not used for anything.

What I think you want is onClick event listeners on the dropdown, and then have an Ajax request fire on each change, the getresults.php file then does a MySQL search and returns the results of the search (not $_GET['loc'] as index.php already knows this value).

Also, use mysqli* or PDO for your database queries, the mysql* set of functions are now deprecated and prone to sql injection.

Comment: please tell me the proper way of doing these with examples of codes

Comment: I am trying to get or to check if $_GET['loc'] is set and it is not returning any value? for the queries in my index.php

Comment: I have a feeling that your $("ul#location li a").click function is not being called, as you do not have an UL element with that id. Is getLoc() being called at all? Test it out, strip out the Ajax and put an alert("hello world"); inside getLoc() then refresh the page and click away.

Comment: Was that the problem then?

Comment: it actually worked not the actual document i posted but i just forgot to reference the ID ajax is working well except that I have other queries which I want to be able to process on index.php like if a user uses the search form and the ?loc variable is set via ajax how will I get the value of $_GET ['loc'] in index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Why have you put your function in document.ready() ?

If it would be me then i would have done like this

```
function getLoc(param){
$.get('getresult.php',{loc:param},function(data){
  //Do some stuff with data
});

}
```

Comment: Its good practice to put it inside document.ready() so that the Ajax runs once the document is fully loaded. Otherwise it can lead to problems where not all of the html/js is fully rendered or loaded and your trying to fire javascript methods.

Comment: Yes i know its a good practice but what's the point in putting a function inside document.ready()?

Comment: So that it is only ready to be called when the document is fully loaded. The document.ready() does exactly what it sounds like, prepare code to be run ONLY when the document is ready and fully loaded.

Comment: Can you show me an example where i would get error if i haven't written my function inside document.ready()

Comment: Dude, how much hand holding do you need? If the page isnt FULLY LOADED (slow internet connection, timeout, downloading some advert, downloading large image etc) and if your function outside of document.ready() tries to modify the DOM or call an Ajax function or read a form value, the function will not work as it has not been downloaded yet or is trying to access parts of the document that have not been fully loaded, so you get a javascript error. Happy?